# Updating DataTable inside as DataSet

Tags: datatable, dataset

In an accounting WPF app we have a number of public DataTables that reload data once a tab is opened. This works great locally as the reports just refer to those tables..

For some more complex reports we have just set up a Web Service to run them and return a PDF... To make it easier I thought of loading these DataTables into a DataSet and then extracting them at the server end. This works perfectly the first time it's run, but then (as best as I can work out so far) it's sending the incorrect (last loaded) data for subsequent reports. Locally it still works as it should but the DataTables we are sending in the DataSet appear to not be updating. Have tried to remove the tables and re-add them again, but that just throws a 'object reference not set' the first time a DataRow is selected from a DataTable at the server.

Must be something very basic I have been missing :-(

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
Private Async Sub RunProfitAndLossOnServer(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim StartDateTB As DateTBx = ReportBalanceSheet_Grid.FindName("BalanceSheet_StartDateTB")
        Dim EndDateTB As DateTBx = ReportBalanceSheet_Grid.FindName("BalanceSheet_EndDateTB")

        ReportStartDate = StartDateTB.Value
        ReportEndDate = EndDateTB.Value
        ReportDate = Today
        ReportName = "Profit and Loss Report"
        PaperLandscape = False
        ReportFontSize = 8
        PopupModals_ReportGenerator()
        If ReportGeneratorRun = True Then

            Dim vPDF() As Byte = Nothing
            'Determine if the Export Dataset has already been created
            If ExportDS Is Nothing Then
                ExportDS = New DataSet
                VariablesDT = New DataTable
                With VariablesDT.Columns
                    .Add("Current_HOA_Name", GetType(String))
                    .Add("Current_HOA_ID", GetType(Integer))
                    .Add("ReportName", GetType(String))
                    .Add("ReportFontSize", GetType(Integer))
                    .Add("ReportStartDate", GetType(Date))
                    .Add("ReportEndDate", GetType(Date))
                    .Add("User_InternationalDate", GetType(Integer))
                    .Add("PaperSize", GetType(String))
                    .Add("PaperLandscape", GetType(Boolean))
                    .Add("Reports_IsSplitGL", GetType(Boolean))
                    .Add("Form_ID", GetType(Integer))
                End With
                With VariablesDT.Rows
                    .Add(Current_HOA_Name, Current_HOA_ID, ReportName, ReportFontSize, ReportStartDate, ReportEndDate, User_InternationalDate, PaperSize, PaperLandscape, False, Form_ID)
                End With
                VariablesDT.TableName = "VariablesDT"
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(VariablesDT)
                ResIncomeDT.TableName = "ResIncomeDT"
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResIncomeDT)
                ResIncNomDT.TableName = "ResIncNomDT"
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResIncNomDT)
                ResExpensesDT.TableName = "ResExpensesDT"
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResExpensesDT)
                ResExpNomDT.TableName = "ResExpNomDT"
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResExpNomDT)
                RevenueDT.TableName = "RevenueDT"
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(RevenueDT)
                ExpensesDT.TableName = "ExpensesDT"
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ExpensesDT)
                RevenueNomDT.TableName = "RevenueNomDT"
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(RevenueNomDT)
                ExpensesNomDT.TableName = "ExpensesNomDT"
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ExpensesNomDT)
            Else

                ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ResIncomeDT")
                ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ResIncNomDT")
                ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ResExpensesDT")
                ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ResExpNomDT")
                ExportDS.Tables.Remove("RevenueDT")
                ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ExpensesDT")
                ExportDS.Tables.Remove("RevenueNomDT")
                ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ExpensesNomDT")

                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResIncomeDT)
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResIncNomDT)
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResExpensesDT)
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResExpNomDT)
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(RevenueDT)
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ExpensesDT)
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(RevenueNomDT)
                ExportDS.Tables.Add(ExpensesNomDT)

                ExportDS.Tables.Remove("VariablesDT")

                For Each row As DataRow In VariablesDT.Rows
                    row("Current_HOA_Name") = Current_HOA_Name
                    row("current_HOA_ID") = Current_HOA_ID
                    row("ReportFontSize") = ReportFontSize
                    row("User_InternationalDate") = User_InternationalDate
                    row("PaperSize") = PaperSize
                    row("PaperLandscape") = PaperLandscape
                    row("Reports_IsSplitGL") = False
                    row("ReportStartDate") = ReportStartDate
                    row("ReportEndDate") = ReportEndDate
                    row("ReportName") = ReportName
                    row("Form_ID") = Form_ID
                Next


                ExportDS.Tables.Add(VariablesDT)

            End If

            Dim vImage As New LoadingImage
                LoadingStarted("Uploading to xSoftware... Please wait...", vImage)
                Await Task.Run(Sub()
                                   Using vService As New Service5Client
                                       vPDF = vService.ReturnProfitAndLossSheet(ExportDS)
                                   End Using
                               End Sub)

                LoadingCompleted("File uploaded to xSoftware...", "File was uploaded and PDF returned...", vImage)

                Dim vFile As String = ByteToFilePath(vPDF)
                If System.IO.File.Exists(vFile) Then
                    Dim P As New Process
                    With P
                        .StartInfo.FileName = vFile
                        .StartInfo.Verb = "Open"
                        .Start()
                    End With
                Else
                    AppBoxError("The file path for the PDF is not valid!")
                End If


            End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Throws an error at the server end if we remove and add the datatables back to the DataSet

```
Dim RevenueData() As DataRow = RevenueDT.Select("FormID = " & Form_ID, "Position")
        Dim ExpenseData() As DataRow = ExpensesDT.Select("FormID = " & Form_ID, "Position")
        Dim RevenueNomData() As DataRow = RevenueNomDT.Select("FormID = " & Form_ID, "Position")
        Dim ExpenseNomData() As DataRow = ExpensesNomDT.Select("FormID = " & Form_ID, "Position")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is

1. Remove the DataTables from the DataSet and add them again (which got us part of the way there)
2. Name the DataTables again!

   ```
   ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ResIncomeDT")
               ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ResIncNomDT")
               ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ResExpensesDT")
               ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ResExpNomDT")
               ExportDS.Tables.Remove("RevenueDT")
               ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ExpensesDT")
               ExportDS.Tables.Remove("RevenueNomDT")
               ExportDS.Tables.Remove("ExpensesNomDT")
               ExportDS.Tables.Remove("VariablesDT")   


    VariablesDT.TableName = "VariablesDT"
               ExportDS.Tables.Add(VariablesDT)
               ResIncomeDT.TableName = "ResIncomeDT"
               ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResIncomeDT)
               ResIncNomDT.TableName = "ResIncNomDT"
               ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResIncNomDT)
               ResExpensesDT.TableName = "ResExpensesDT"
               ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResExpensesDT)
               ResExpNomDT.TableName = "ResExpNomDT"
               ExportDS.Tables.Add(ResExpNomDT)
               RevenueDT.TableName = "RevenueDT"
               ExportDS.Tables.Add(RevenueDT)
               ExpensesDT.TableName = "ExpensesDT"
               ExportDS.Tables.Add(ExpensesDT)
               RevenueNomDT.TableName = "RevenueNomDT"
               ExportDS.Tables.Add(RevenueNomDT)
               ExpensesNomDT.TableName = "ExpensesNomDT"
               ExportDS.Tables.Add(ExpensesNomDT)
   ```

Now it appears to be working correctly :-)